# Is this sentence grammatically correct? (Concerned with the usage of "have less to do with")

Tags: grammaticality

> I think “solitude” here has less to do with loneliness or isolation, than with serving as a prerequisite for recollection and reflection.

I think the sentence reads a bit off, particularly around the second half, but I'm not sure. Help?

Comment: It's fine grammatically, the second half is just a bit of a mouthful. Can be simplified. The comma is unnecessary.

Comment: To simplify, "with serving" can be omitted.

Comment: _Have less/more to do with ... than with ..._ is the construction, and all parts are required to make it a comparative construction. _Than_ is the key; it only occurs with comparatives, and it always marks the baseline for comparison. _Have to do with_ means _is involved with_, without any details; it's very vague and apt for such a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it's a bit awkward.  I think that stems from comparing "having to do with" and "serving as".

> I think "solitude" here has less to do with being a reference to
>   loneliness and isolation, than with serving as a prerequisite for
>   recollection and reflection.

Or perhaps even better:

> I think "solitude" here serves more as a prerequisite for recollection
>   and reflection than as a reference to loneliness or isolation